# Fix Detail Band Relative To Top In The Page It Is Being Printed

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *iReport* version 4.0.1. I am facing a problem in which I want to display some information that must come on the 2nd page only. So, its neither a FOOTER nor a LAST-PAGE-FOOTER. I am using *iReport* for generating the jrxml files and the design looks something like below.

{HEADER}
{DETAIL-BAND-1} Remarks: Till this point my 1st page finishes
{DETAIL-BAND-2} Remarks: This is coming from a sub-report
{DETAIL-BAND-3} Remarks : This is coming from a sub-report
Some Random Empty Space Is Left
{DETAIL-BAND-4} Remarks: This is where my 2nd page footer needs to come.

.
.
.
.

{Lots of Bands}
.
.
{MAIN-REPORT-FINISHES}

So, I want the footer (actually it is not a footer, its some detail that only need to come on the 2nd page of the pdf generated by JR) to be fixed relative to the top of the page in which it is being printed. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the property "Print When Expression" and then you can use a variable that already exists in your iReport called PAGE_COUNT and it will be printed only when this expression is true.